# What is the value of n such that n! = 3! × 5! × 7!

Tags: factorial, telescopic-series

does this use the telescopic series if it does how do you express the general term? 
I have no idea. I need some help

Comment: Well, there aren't many cases to check...if $n≥11$ then $11\,|\,n!$ but it doesn't divide the right hand.

Comment: 3!×5!×7!=1×2×3×4×5×6×7×1×2×3×1×2×3×4×5=1×2×3×4×5×6×7×(2×4)×(3×3)×(2×5)=1×2×3×4×5×6×7×8×9×10=10!

Comment: Let me [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+3!5!7!%3Dx!++For+x) it for you.

Comment: @mvw Don't take the author the possibility to work out something himself.

Comment: $n = \Gamma^{-1}(\Gamma(4) \Gamma(6) \Gamma(8))-1$

Comment: @MPW quite an overkill and only feasible with a computer.

Comment: is there any definite way to get the answer without observation

Comment: no could someone explain the whole thing

Comment: @JohnTom OK, lulu gave the upper bound. We need prime factor $5$ twice, hence $10$ is the smallest possible value. Now, you just have to verify $$8\cdot 9\cdot 10=120\cdot 6$$

Comment: oh thanks peter it makes sense now

Comment: and@MPW introducing the gamma function is gonna complicate a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $3!\times 5!=720=8\times 9\times 10=\frac{10!}{7!}$, $n=10$.